# What would it take for wordpress to email users a random question

Tags: php, mysql, html, email

What technologies would have to be implemented into a website that would automatically generate questions and send them to my users email? Similar to stackoverflow.com and vark.com except the questions would come from a data base that I created not other users. I have no Idea even what language could do this... please help.

Comment: Also make sure you've gotten permission from your users to do this (assuming US).  Spam complaints are serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP and MySQL would do the job just fine. It would work for the rest of the site as well.

www.w3schools.com - check it up for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a database of users' emails, a database of questions and an email system.  You don't even need to make it web-based.  Look at Python's [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) or PHP's [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. In conjunction with basic randomization and SQL, you're set.